# How can i store and retrieve a integer value in background service?

Tags: android, android-service

I need to store only one integer in the phone from the application. 
This integer value is required even when the application is stopped.
So i am trying to run a background service and to store the integer in it.
How can i store and retrieve the value from the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store that integer value.